# Porque a minha Estrutura de Condição está atribuindo um valor a uma variável?

Tags: if, visualg

O meu código abaixo representa o cenário de guardar um gabarito de 5 questões, onde:

- Cada questão vale 2 pontos
- Verificar se 3 alunos irão acertar o Gabarito
- Calcular a Nota Individual de Cada Aluno
- Calcular a Média da Turma

A minha dúvida está exatamente ali na parte de somar as notas dos alunos, mais especificamente nesta expressão: `soma <- soma + 2`.

A soma "une" os valores da `nota[a]`, porém não coloquei o valor na soma para ela receber o mesmo.

- a) Porque isto acontece?
- b) Porque neste local é utilizado o `+ 2`?.
- c) O vetor nota[a] de fato guardaria um valor?

**O Local da Dúvida:**

```
  nota[a] <- nota[a] + 2
  soma <- soma + nota[a]
```

**Meu Código:**

```
 Var i,a,c: inteiro    
    resp,gab: vetor[1..5] de caractere   
    nome: vetor[1..3] de caractere
    nota: vetor[1..5] de real
    m,soma: real

    Inicio

    Para i <- 1 ate 5 faca
            Escreva("Digite o gabarito ", i)
            Leia(gab[i]) 
    FimPara
    Para a <- 1 ate 3 faca
            EscrevaL("ALUNOS ", a)
            Escreva("Nome: ")
            Leia(nome[a])
            Para c <- 1 ate 5 faca
                 Escreva("Digite a questão ", c)
                 Leia(resp[c])
                 Se (gab[i]=resp[c]) entao
                    EscrevaL(" acertou a ", c)
                    nota[a] <- nota[a] + 2
                    soma <- soma + 2
                 FimSe
            FimPara
            m <- soma/3
    FimPara 
    Para a <- 1 ate 3 faca
            EscrevaL(nome[a]: 10, nota[a])
    FimPara
    Escreva("Média da Turma: ", m)
```

Comment: Seja bem vinda Ale, este código é seu? Poderia editar a perguntar e colocar o exercicio?  Ou comentar as principais linhas do código? Facilitaria para te ajudar

Comment: Luiz, vê se ficou fácil entender a minha dúvida agora. Por favor, se não ficou claro me diga que eu edito novamente.

Comment: Ficou claro, sim, alias estou mexendo no seu código agora, já possuo algumas respostas para suas perguntas, o problema é que a comparação `gab[i]=resp[c]` está retornando falsa e não estou entrando no laço da soma, vc está conseguindo executar está parte?

Comment: Aqui está dando certo, sim.

Comment: Vou sanar suas dúvidas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seja bem vindo(a).

De inicio, para corrigir seu código você precisa alterar essa linha:

```
Se (gab[i]=resp[c]) entao
```

Para:

```
Se (gab[c]=resp[c]) entao //mudei o 'i' pelo 'c'
```

Até porque do primeiro modo, o i não era atualizado, e por isso você sempre comparava a resposta com um valor do gabarito.

Sobre a pergunta do nota[a], não entendi o que você quis dizer com

> "A "soma" junta os valores de toda nota[a] mas não coloquei valor nela
>   pra ela receber nada. Por que isso acontece?".

Sobre porque usar +2 ao invés de nota[a] no soma. Acontece que, da forma como está o código, toda vez que você coloca a resposta do primeiro aluno a uma questão, ele atualiza o valor de nota[a] e de soma com o mesmo valor. Assim, quando responder as 5 questões para o primeiro aluno, o valor de nota[1°aluno] vai ser igual ao de soma.

Já quando ir para o segundo aluno, nota[2°aluno] inicia no zero, enquanto soma já tem o valor da pontuação do primeiro aluno, por isso, se você fizer 'soma <- soma + nota[a]' quando o segundo aluno acertar a primeira questão, vai ser somado zero à variável soma (soma <- soma + nota[a], sendo que nota[a] é zero).

Uma alternativa para poder usar 'soma <- soma + nota[a]' seria fazer o código como abaixo:

```
    Var

i,a,c: inteiro
resp,gab: vetor[1..5] de caractere
nome: vetor[1..3] de caractere
nota: vetor[1..5] de real
m,soma: real

Inicio

Para i <- 1 ate 5 faca
        Escreva("Digite o gabarito ", i)
        Leia(gab[i])
FimPara
Para a <- 1 ate 3 faca
        EscrevaL("ALUNOS ", a)
        Escreva("Nome: ")
        Leia(nome[a])
        Para c <- 1 ate 5 faca
             Escreva("Digite a questão ", c)
             Leia(resp[c])
             Se (gab[c]=resp[c]) entao
                EscrevaL(" acertou a ", c)
                nota[a] <- nota[a] + 2

             FimSe
        FimPara
        soma <- soma + nota[a] //essa instrução está fora do 'para' que itera 'a'
FimPara
m <- soma/3 //essa linha pode ficar fora dos dois 'para'
Para a <- 1 ate 3 faca
        EscrevaL(nome[a]: 10, nota[a])
FimPara
Escreva("Média da Turma: ", m)


Fimalgoritmo
```

Não tenho certeza se fui claro, ou se respondi(certo) todas suas dúvidas, qualquer coisa, edita sua pergunta para abordar os outros pontos de dúvidas.

Comment: O código do Vinícius Girotto era exatamente o jeito que queria fazer, porém cada um que respondeu me ajudou a entender o que estava tentando fazer e sanou minhas dúvidas, muito obrigada a todos!

Comment: Que bom que te ajudou Ale. Por algum motivo, alguém negativou essa minha resposta e uma a outra pergunta(de 15 dias atrás), e não entendi o porquê. Se alguém notou algum erro nas respostas, pelo menos diga qual o erro.

Answer (score 2):

Note que aqui:

```
 Se (gab[i]=resp[c]) entao
```

a variável i tem o valor que possuía no final do loop de leitura do gabarito.
Creio que deveria ser:

```
 Se (gab[c]=resp[c]) entao
```

Você precisa atribuir um valor incial a cada posição do vetor nota, por exemplo `nota[a] <- 0` logo após a leitura do nome.

Você recalcula a média para cada aluno e não calcula a média da turma, imprime apenas o cálculo do último aluno.

```
Var
    i,a,c: inteiro    
    resp,gab: vetor[1..5] de caractere   
    nome: vetor[1..3] de caractere
    nota: vetor[1..3] de real
    m,soma: real
Inicio
    Para i <- 1 ate 5 faca
        Escreva("Digite o gabarito ", i)
        Leia(gab[i]) 
    FimPara
    soma <- 0
    Para a <- 1 ate 3 faca
        EscrevaL("ALUNOS ", a)
        Escreva("Nome: ")
        Leia(nome[a])
        nota[a] <- 0
        Para c <- 1 ate 5 faca
            Escreva("Digite a questão ", c)
            Leia(resp[c])
            Se (gab[c]=resp[c]) entao
                EscrevaL(" acertou a ", c)
                nota[a] <- nota[a] + 2
                soma <- soma + 2
            FimSe
        FimPara
    FimPara 
    Para a <- 1 ate 3 faca
             EscrevaL(nome[a]: 10, nota[a])
    FimPara
    m <- soma/3
    Escreva("Média da Turma: ", m)
fimalgoritmo
```

Answer (score 0):

> A "soma" junta os valores de nota[a] porém não coloquei valor na
>   "soma" pra ela receber. Por que isso acontece?

Isto acontece, por que você colocou a operação + 2 na mesma linha, como você não iniciou a variável soma ela vale 0, porém na mesma linha você atribui 2 a variável, veja abaixo:

```
soma <- soma + 2.
```

Seria exatamente o mesmo que:

```
soma = 0 + 2
```

> E mais uma pergunta, o porquê ali é + 2 ?

Por que você tem 5 perguntas e a nota máxima vale 10, portanto se você tivesse 10 perguntas o incremento seria de `+1`

> Por que não poderia ser desse jeito?

```
nota[a] <- nota[a] + 2

soma <- soma + nota[a]
```

Você está correta o melhor jeito de faze-lo é assim!

> Aí a nota[a] vai pra "soma" e ela de fato guardaria um valor ?

Novamente está correta, guardaria o valor, e você precisará de ambas variáveis `soma` e `nota[a]`, pois elas são usadas em etapas diferentes do seu código.

Fiz algumas correções no seu código:

```
Inicio
// Seção de Comandos, procedimento, funções, operadores, etc... 
 Para i <- 1 ate 5 faca
        Escreva("Digite o gabarito ", i)
        Leia(gab[i])
FimPara
Para a <- 1 ate 3 faca
        EscrevaL("ALUNOS ", a)
        Escreva("Nome: ")
        Leia(nome[a])
        Para c <- 1 ate 5 faca
             Escreva("Digite a questão ", c)
             Leia(resp[c])
             Se (gab[c]=resp[c]) entao
                EscrevaL(" acertou a ", c)
                nota[a] <- nota[a] + 2
                soma <- soma + nota[a]
                senão
                 Escreval(" errou a questão: ", c)
                                       // Evite colocar apenas o se.. então, sem um  
                                      //fechamento de senão, pois se não entrar no 
                                     //primeiro laço informará o usuário em qual laço 
                                     //entrou
             FimSe
        FimPara
        m <- soma/3
FimPara
Para a <- 1 ate 3 faca
        EscrevaL(nome[a], " de 10 pontos você tirou: ", nota[a], " pontos")   
                                 //Coloquei mais texto para informar bem o usuário de 
                                 //quanto foi a nota e qual seria a nota máxima
FimPara
Escreva("Média da Turma: ", m)

Fimalgoritmo
```